# coefficient magnitude interpretation

Tags: regression-coefficients

I have a question regarding the interpretation of coefficient magnitude (not coefficient) in linear regression when the dependent variable is log-transformed.

When the y is not log-transformed the interpretation is like the following
an increase of x (independent variable) by one standard deviation is associated with the increase of y (dependent variable) by 2.63% of its standard deviation.

But I do not know if this is also true when y is log-transformed.In other words,
How should I consider percent standard deviation changes? (because the model is of percent changes in )

A continuation of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605945/coefficient-magnitude) question

Thank you

Comment: A continuation of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/605945/247274) question

Comment: This is a [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log*+interpret+regression+coefficient+-logistic).